# rss hash dpdk compute as NIC

Tags: c++, dpdk, mellanox, multiqueue

I am using mellanox Connectx6, dpdk 22

'MT2892 Family [ConnectX-6 Dx] 101d' if=ens5f1 drv=mlx5_core unused=igb_uio

I configure port with multiqueue and split traffic according to ip+port

I want to calculate the hash as the nic do, to be able to load balance traffic ( from another card ) - the information is inside the packet and not in in ip and transport layer. For this purpose i need to be able to calculate the hash value as the nic do for the first nic.

Here is the code i use to split traffic to rx queues

```
        /*rte flow*/
        const int MAX_PATTERN_IN_FLOW = 10;
        const int MAX_ACTIONS_IN_FLOW = 10;
        
        struct rte_flow_attr attr;
        
        struct rte_flow_item pattern[MAX_PATTERN_IN_FLOW];
        struct rte_flow_action actions[MAX_ACTIONS_IN_FLOW];
        struct rte_flow *flow;
        struct rte_flow_error error;

        memset(pattern, 0, sizeof(pattern));
        memset(actions, 0, sizeof(actions));

        /* Set the rule attribute, only ingress packets will be checked. 8< */
        memset(&attr, 0, sizeof(struct rte_flow_attr));
        attr.ingress = 1;

        pattern[0].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_ETH;
        pattern[0].spec = NULL;

        pattern[1].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_IPV4;
        pattern[1].spec = NULL;

        pattern[2].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_GRE;
        pattern[2].spec = NULL;

        pattern[3].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_ETH;
        pattern[3].spec = NULL;

        pattern[4].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_IPV4;
        pattern[4].spec = NULL;

        pattern[5].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_UDP;
        pattern[5].spec = NULL;

        // end the pattern array 
        pattern[6].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_END;

        struct rte_flow_action_rss rss_conf;
        uint16_t queues[pi_nNumRxQueues];
        rss_conf.func = RTE_ETH_HASH_FUNCTION_DEFAULT;
        uint64_t hf = RTE_ETH_RSS_IP | RTE_ETH_RSS_TCP | RTE_ETH_RSS_UDP | RTE_ETH_RSS_SCTP;
        hf &= pi_devInfo.flow_type_rss_offloads;
        rss_conf.types = hf;
        rss_conf.queue_num = pi_nNumRxQueues;
        for (int nqQueueIndex= 0; nqQueueIndex < pi_nNumRxQueues; nqQueueIndex++)
                queues[nqQueueIndex] = nqQueueIndex;

        rss_conf.queue = queues;
        
        rss_conf.key_len = 0;
        rss_conf.key = NULL;
        rss_conf.level = 2;

        // create the drop action 
        actions[0].type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_RSS;
        actions[0].conf = &rss_conf;
        actions[1].type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_END;

        // validate and create the flow rule 
        if (rte_flow_validate(pi_nPort, &attr, pattern, actions, &error)==0)
        {
            flow = rte_flow_create(pi_nPort, &attr, pattern, actions, &error);
            if(flow){//success}
            else{//error}
        }
        else {error}
        
    }
```

And this is how i tried to get the hash value saved in the mbuf, but failed

```
uint8_t rss_hash_default_key[] = {
    0x2c, 0xc6, 0x81, 0xd1,
    0x5b, 0xdb, 0xf4, 0xf7,
    0xfc, 0xa2, 0x83, 0x19,
    0xdb, 0x1a, 0x3e, 0x94,
    0x6b, 0x9e, 0x38, 0xd9,
    0x2c, 0x9c, 0x03, 0xd1,
    0xad, 0x99, 0x44, 0xa7,
    0xd9, 0x56, 0x3d, 0x59,
    0x06, 0x3c, 0x25, 0xf3,
    0xfc, 0x1f, 0xdc, 0x2a,
};

static inline uint32_t
do_softrss(struct rte_mbuf *m)
{
    uint32_t input_len;
    struct rte_ipv4_tuple ipv4_tuple;
    
    char * pRawPacket = static_cast<char*>(rte_pktmbuf_mtod(pi_mbuf, void* ));
    IpHeader * pIpHeader = (IpHeader *)(pRawPacket + offsetOfIp);
    if(pIpHeader->GetVersion()==4)
    {
        ipv4_tuple.src_addr = rte_be_to_cpu_32(pIpHeader->dwSrcAddressBigEndian);
        ipv4_tuple.dst_addr = rte_be_to_cpu_32(pIpHeader->dwDstAddressBigEndian);
        ipv4_tuple.sport = *(uint16_t*)(pRawPacket + transportLayerOffset);
        ipv4_tuple.dport = *(uint16_t*)(pRawPacket + transportLayerOffset+2);
        input_len = RTE_THASH_V4_L3_LEN;
        return rte_softrss_be((uint32_t *)&ipv4_tuple, input_len, rss_key_be);

    }
    return 0;
}
new_rss = do_softrss(mbuf_pointer);
std::cout<< std::hex << mbuf_pointer->hash.rss << " -> " << new_rss << std::dec << std::endl;
```

And i get a different value than the mbuf_pointer->hash.rss

```
5ed28a5c -> 33eb33eb
974c1896 -> 24e224e2
1edf1638 -> 21752175
8a54c19 -> 80638063
459a6f76 -> 1b351b35
1cdf1d1c -> e53be53b
```

I understand it is possible to do it, but i don't get the same value

```
ethtool -i ens5f0
driver: mlx5_core
version: 5.8-3.0.7
firmware-version: 22.32.2004 (MT_0000000437)
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:83:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

Comment: The RSS key used by the hardware manufacturer may be different from the RSS key you use. Have you tried setting the key inside the device?
Or set rss key in flow action ?

Comment: I also tried setting the key but also didn't get same value as   in mbuf 
rss_conf.key_len = sizeof(rss_hash_default_key);
rss_conf.key =rss_hash_default_key ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be two main reasons why the mismatch is observed:

- L4 port numbers having unsuitable byte order when passed to `rte_softrss_be`
- the use of `RTE_THASH_V4_L3_LEN` instead of `RTE_THASH_V4_L4_LEN`

Given the OP code snippet, consider to fix this as follows:

```
ipv4_tuple.src_addr = rte_be_to_cpu_32(pIpHeader->dwSrcAddressBigEndian);
ipv4_tuple.dst_addr = rte_be_to_cpu_32(pIpHeader->dwDstAddressBigEndian);
ipv4_tuple.sport = rte_be_to_cpu_16(*(uint16_t*)(pRawPacket + transportLayerOffset));
ipv4_tuple.dport = rte_be_to_cpu_16(*(uint16_t*)(pRawPacket + transportLayerOffset+2));
input_len = RTE_THASH_V4_L4_LEN;
```

As for the key, please make sure that

- the given key (`rss_hash_default_key` from the OP snippet) is passed to flow action RSS:

```
rss_conf.key_len = RTE_DIM(rss_hash_default_key);
rss_conf.key = rss_hash_default_key;
```

- `rss_key_be` passed to `rte_softrss_be` is derived from `rss_hash_default_key` as follows:

```
uint8_t rss_key_be[40];

rte_convert_rss_key((uint32_t *)rss_hash_default_key,
                    (uint32_t *)rss_key_be,
                    RTE_DIM(rss_key_be));
```

Comment: Thank you , I found it also, forgot to update the ticket 
Changing RTE_THASH_V4_L4_LEN really solved the problem
I had also another problem with the parallel load balance but i also found answer about using symetric hashing